# How do I set combobox text

Tags: wpf, winforms, combobox

lets say I have combobox and I have set data source (string list) to it. I don't want to include **- Select -** to the list. is it possible to display - Select - on dropdown without adding it to datasource. (Is it possible to display text which is not in the list?)

Comment: is it wpf or winforms combo ?

Comment: @Muds- In either way I want to achieve it

Comment: see my answer, works on wpf combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make combobox editable and readonly and then set its text.

```
.IsEditable = True
.IsReadOnly = True 
.Text = "----Select----"
```